# Swift - remove single backslash

Tags: ios, swift, backslash

this is maybe stupid question but I'm new to swift and i actually can't figure this out.

I have API which returns url as string "**http:\/\/xxx**". I don't know how to store URL returned from API in this format. I can't store it to variable because of backslash.

From apple doc:

> ...string cannot contain an unescaped backslash (\), ...

Is there any way how to store string like this or how remove these single backslashes or how to work with this?

Thank you for every advice.

Comment: Where is the backslash?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't noticed that backslashes disappeared. I have added them to url.

Comment: use it:
myString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\/", with: "\\",options: .literal, range: nil)

Comment: You can use `#"String with back slash inside"#`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just replace those backslashes, for example:

```swift
let string2 = string1.replacing("\\", with: "")
```

Or, to avoid the confusion over the fact that the backslash within a normal string literal is escaped with yet another backslash, we can use an [extended string delimiter](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/stringsandcharacters/#Extended-String-Delimiters) of `#"` and `"#`:

```swift
let string2 = string1.replacing(#"\"#, with: "")
```

But, if possible, you really should fix that API that is returning those backslashes, as that's obviously incorrect. The author of that code was apparently under the mistaken impression that forward slashes must be escaped, but this is not true.

Bottom line, the API should be fixed to not insert these backslashes, but until that's remedied, you can use the above to remove any backslashes that may occur.

---

In the discussion in the comments below, there seems to be enormous confusion about backslashes in strings. So, let's step back for a second and discuss “string literals”. As [the documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/stringsandcharacters/#String-Literals) says, a string literal is:

> You can include predefined `String` values within your code as string literals. A string literal is a fixed sequence of textual characters surrounded by a pair of double quotes (`""`).

Note, a string literal is just a representation of a particular fixed sequence of characters in your code. But, this should not be confused with the underlying `String` object itself. The key difference between a string literal and the underlying `String` object is that a string literal allows one to use a backslash as an "escape" character, used when representing special characters (or doing [string interpolation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/stringsandcharacters/#String-Interpolation)). As [the documentation says](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/stringsandcharacters/#Special-Characters-in-String-Literals):

> String literals can include the following special characters:
>
> - The escaped special characters `\0` (null character), `\\` (backslash), `\t` (horizontal tab), `\n` (line feed), `\r` (carriage return), `\"` (double quote) and `\'` (single quote)
> - An arbitrary Unicode scalar, written as `\u{n}`, where `n` is a 1–8 digit hexadecimal number with a value equal to a valid Unicode code point

So, you are correct that in a string literal, as the excerpt you quoted above points out, you cannot have an unescaped backslash. Thus, whenever you want to represent a single backslash in a string literal, you represent that with a `\\`.

Thus, the above `replacing` means “look through the `string1`, find all occurrences of a single backslash, and replace them with an empty string (i.e. remove the backslash).”

Consider:

```swift
let string1 = "foo\\bar"

print(string1)                    // this will print "foo\bar"
print(string1.count)              // this will print "7", not "8"

let string2 = string1.replacing("\\", with: "")

print(string2)                    // this will print "foobar"
print(string2.count)              // this will print "6"
```

A little confusingly, if you look at `string1` in the “Variables” view of the “Debug” panel or within playground, it will show a string literal representation (i.e. backslashes will appear as `"\\"`). But don't be confused. When you see `\\` in the string literal, there is actually only a single backslash within the actual string. But if you `print` the value or look at the actual characters, there is only a single backslash in the string, itself.

In short, do not conflate the escaping of the backslash within a string literal (for example, the parameters to `replacing`) and the single backslash that exists in the underlying string.

Comment: But i don't have "\\" i have only "\" so i can't even store it to string (at least i don't know how).

Comment: Yes, but "\" is a reserved character, indicating that the next character indicates what to do (e.g. `\n` is newline, `\r` is return, etc.). The way you represent "\" in a string literal, itself, in a string is "\\". I know it's confusing, but that's how it works.

Comment: Thank you for information. I actually understand all those things but i just wanted to know if I can do anything if i get string in this format. So basically if i get string with "\" i can do nothing? Because i can't store this string to replace "\" to "\\" in swift.

Comment: No, `string1.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\", withString: "")` _does_ replace occurrences of a single backslash with "". The way you specify "single backslash" in a string literal is "\\".

Comment: See [Special Characters in String Literals](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID295) in the _Strings and Characters_ chapter of _The Swift Programming Language._

Comment: I still don't understand how to use `string1.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\", withString: "")` if I'm not able do `var string1 = "http:\/\/"`

Comment: `let string1 = "http:\\/\\/..."; print(string1);` and you'll see you have one backslash before each slash. Then `let string2 = string1.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\", withString: ""); print(string2)`

Comment: Yes i can add extra backslash if I'm testing it in local variable but if i (app) download string with backslash from API I still see no option how work with string like "http:\/\/".

Comment: I give up: I've shown you how to remove single backslashes from the string returned from your API, and you clearly don't believe me (but I'd wager you haven't tried it on the string returned from your API, either).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I actually tried all this only with local variable (which doesn't work) because API part is not implemented yet. I will try all this when API will be implemented. Thank a lot again for your time and advices.

Comment: Very good. By the way, if the API stuff is still in progress, just have them not include those backslashes in the first place. Clearly whomever designed that was under the mistaken impression that the slash characters of the scheme needed to be escaped, but they don't. You have to escape backslash character, but not a forward slash character. It's much better to just fix the problem rather than programming around a faulty interface.

Comment: Rob, have you tried this with Swift 2 ? I can't believe I'm running into the issue that  let test = "hello\\playground"  actually gives two backslash in the string instead of one !

Comment: @Xav - Yes, I'm sure. That right panel in the playground will escape strings, too. But if you do `print(test)` and look at the debug panel, below, you'll see it prints only one backslash. Or look at `let length = test.characters.count` and you'll see it says `16`, not `17`.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I have written an Insert query but it is getting failed due to single backslash.
Query is. :  "insert into Users (emailId, password) values ('ios@gmail.com', 'Nunnumann@1');"
and at run time it is showing like that : "insert into Users (emailId, password) values (\'ios@gmail.com\', \'Nunnumann@1\');"
Any solution for this ?

Comment: @i_Intiution - First, you shouldn't escape `'` characters with backslash inside a string literal at all, so this is somewhat moot. Second, if doing SQL, you should avoid inserting values into the SQL by building the string, but rather you'd use `?` placeholders, e.g. `insert into Users (emailId, password) values (?, ?)` and then bind values to those two place holders via the SQLite API

Comment: @SujitBaranwal - Then your situation is obviously different. But we cannot help you without seeing a [reproducible example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. I would suggest you [post your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with a MCVE rather than posting comments under other people’s questions/answers.

Answer (score 5):

I found I was having this same issue when trying to encode my objects to JSON. Depending on if you're using the newer `JSONEncoder` class to parse your JSON and you're supporting a minimum of iOS 13, you can use the `.withoutEscapingSlashes` output formatting:

```swift
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.outputFormatting = .withoutEscapingSlashes

try encoder.encode(yourJSONObject)
```

Answer (score 3):

Please check the below code.

```
let jsonStr = "[{\"isSelected\":true,\"languageProficiencies\":[{\"isSelected\":true,\"name\":\"Advance\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Proficient\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Basic\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Below Basic\"}],\"name\":\"English\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"languageProficiencies\":[{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Advance\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Proficient\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Basic\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Below Basic\"}],\"name\":\"Malay\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"languageProficiencies\":[{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Advance\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Proficient\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Basic\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Below Basic\"}],\"name\":\"Chinese\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"languageProficiencies\":[{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Advance\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Proficient\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Basic\"},{\"isSelected\":false,\"name\":\"Below Basic\"}],\"name\":\"Tamil\"}]"
let convertedStr = jsonStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
print(convertedStr)
```

Comment: This is not working

Answer (score 3):

I've solved with this piece of code:

```
let convertedStr = jsonString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\/", with: "/")
```

Comment: I change it to 
myString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\/", with: "\\")
and it work fine

Answer (score 1):

Include a backslash in a string by adding an extra backslash.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I don't know how to add backslash because I can't do `var str = "http:\/\/"` or am I missing something?

Comment: Now you adding an escape character plus a forward-slash. You can add a backslah by adding the escape character followed by the backslash itself (the escaped character). var str="http:\\\\www."

Comment: Come to think of it, for a website you need the forward slash. So you can easily assign: var str = "http://www.ebay.nl"

Answer (score 1):

To remove single backslash,try this

```
let replaceStr = backslashString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")
```

Comment: If you add this code, all the double quotes are getting replaced